# Dynamically selecting variables from a joined table

Tags: sql-server

I have a task which requires selecting columns from TableB where PrimaryKey=PrimaryKey from TableA.

Table B's columns can change.

I need to select everything from TableB except 'ColumnA' the PrimaryKey

```
DECLARE @COLUMNS VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @Columns = SubString ((  SELECT + ', ' + 'Alias'+ QUOTENAME(Column_name)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE Table_name ='TableB'
AND COLUMN_NAME !='ColumnB'
FOR XML PATH ( '' ) ), 3, 1000) 
print @COLUMNS
```

This is what I was going to use in the select columns stage, but I am trying to figure out if there is a better way, since table aliases will change throughout the program so I dont want to have to adjust this every time.

It might be that I am not going about this in the right way at all.

Some background:

```
DECLARE @TreatmentTableVariables TABLE(ParameterCode VARCHAR(64), Value varchar(64))

INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('SourceCode','NS')
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('TripFirstTravelDate','')
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('PaxType','')
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('ChannelID','')
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('RoleName','')
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('TripOriginLocationCode',NULL)
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('TripDestinationLocationCode',NULL)
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('ExternalBookingID',NULL)
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('NumberOfPassengers',NULL)
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('FareClass',NULL)
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('TripType',NULL)
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('BookingWeekday','Monday')
INSERT @TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('TripOriginCountryCode','')

SELECT  DISTINCT ParameterCode, Value
INTO  Staging.tmpParameterCodes
FROM @TreatmentTableVariables;

SET @ParameterCodesToPivot = (SELECT '['+LEFT(ParameterCode, LEN(ParameterCode) - 2)
                              FROM (
                                        SELECT ParameterCode + '],['
                                        FROM Staging.tmpParameterCodes
                                        where Value IS NOT NULL 
                                        FOR XML PATH ('')

                                    ) c (ParameterCode)
                              )     

SET @sqlquery = '
    SELECT *
    INTO 
   Staging.tmpTreatmentInputParameters
    FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                tip.TreatmentID,
                tip.ParameterCode,
                tip.ClientCode,
                tip.Value
            FROM AnalyticsDW.TreatmentInputParameter tip
            inner join Staging.tmpParameterCodes TPC
            on tip.ParameterCode=TPC.ParameterCode
            --join Staging.tmpFlattenTreatmentData1 t on tip.TreatmentID=t.TreatmentID
            Where 
            --tip.TreatmentID between @MinTreatmentID and @MaxTreatmentID
            --and
             TPC.Value IS NOT NULL
             and (TPC.Value=tip.Value or TPC.Value='''')
        )p
        PIVOT
        (
            MIN(Value)
            FOR ParameterCode IN ( '+ @ParameterCodesToPivot +' )
        ) 

        AS PVT'
```

I am creating this table with a bunch of variables where I will be using to see values of a dynamic table (@TreatmentTableVariables) for each instance of TreatmentID (the primary key).

So a resulting table (Staging.tmpParameterCodes) would look like

```
DECLARE @goal TABLE(
ParameterCode varchar(100),
Value VARCHAR(100)
)
insert into @goal values
('BookingWeekday','Monday'),
('ChannelID',''),
('ExternalBookingID',NULL)
```

And then I have a big long set of queries to do different things with X number of set variables, and then the variables from this @goal table. In this case, BookingWeekday and Channel ID would be used since they arent NULL values. In different places I would need to select or group by on these variables. If I were only going to select these variables from the table, I would use:

```
DECLARE @COLUMNS VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @Columns = SubString ((  SELECT + ', ' + 'Alias'+ QUOTENAME(Column_name)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE Table_name ='goal'
AND COLUMN_NAME !='ColumnB'
FOR XML PATH ( '' ) ), 3, 1000) 
print @COLUMNS
```

But as I said before I want to think of a more versitle solution instead of creating different copies of the above code to use with group by or select etc.

Just looking for ideas on what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, non-dynamic approach would be to:

`SELECT * INTO #aTempTable`,

and then `ALTER #aTempTable` to drop the column you don't want.

Then `SELECT * FROM #aTempTable`